# How to write a file then import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I need to write some variables to a file then import it. Whenever I try to run it, though, the console says that the variable doesn't exist.

`file_writer.py`:

```
target = open('save.py', 'w')
target.write('x = 2')
from save import *
print(x)
```

`save.py`:

```
x = 2
```

`save.py` was empty before running `file_writer.py`.

Comment: You never `.close` the file, so it probably hasn't been flushed to disk. Also you should really open files with the context manager `with`: `with open('save.py', 'w') as target:`.

Comment: Thank you! Still very new to python, so its nice to get help with style as well!

Comment: Why would you need to do this?  I could understand if you needed to import this from some other code, but there are easier ways to assign to variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following snippet alternatively:

```
with open('vars.txt', 'w') as file_:
    file_.write('x = 2')

with open('vars.txt', 'r') as file_:
    exec(file_.read())

print(x)
# 2
```

Comment: There is only one thing worse than using `exec()`: showing others how to use it.

Comment: what makes exec() bad?

Comment: @DYZ: In this case it's not much different from `from save import *` though, as you could just as easily insert evil code there.
@CardWallets you generally don't want to use `exec()` to execute arbitrary code given by the user as it might do pretty much anything. Including stealing your files, or erasing your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

For instance you can save your data in a structured JSON file:

```
import json

filename = 'data.json'

data = {
    'x': 1,
    'y': 2
}

with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        loaded_data = json.load(f)
except IOError:
    print('File not found.')

# Print all data:
print(json.dumps(loaded_data, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
# {
#     "x": 1,
#     "y": 2
# }

# Print selected elements:
print(loaded_data.get('x'))
print(loaded_data.get('y'))
print(loaded_data.get('z', 3))  # with a default value
```